# How to implement back button with ajax calls made

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, web-applications

I have a single page web application which allows user to enter genre, date range and other bunch of inputs.

Now i read all those inputs and make a ajax post request to server. Server is on java spring mvc.

Everything works fine. Now i want to create a back functionality.

So after doing couple of searches if user wants to go back to 4th or 5th previous search he should be able to do that.

I saw history.back(-1) but it doesnt suit here. because ajax call doesnt change url. My Url is always localhost:8080/MyImdb

the ajax call looks like:

```
xhr = $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            async: true,
            dataType: 'json',
            url: location.href + 'getResults',          
            data: ({date:dateRange, genre:genre, cast:cast }),

            success:function(json) {
                processData(json);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                var error = "jqXHR: " + jqXHR + "; ; ; ; status: " + textStatus + "; ; ; ; errorThrown: " + errorThrown;
                console.log(error);
            }
        }).done(function() {
            hideLoadingIndicator();
        });
```

One idea i am having is to put all the post data into object. and save those objects in a stack. 
Now create a back button. when user clicks it pop the object from stack and make a ajax post request with the popped object and parallely update the input boxes in the front end

Is this the standard way or is there some library built to do this.

I looked into jquery history plugin and hashchange events but i dont think they will fit my above case as the url is always same.

Did any of you guys ran into this case?

Comment: I just saved the searches made - almost like the stack solution you mentioned

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement a router which listens to hashchange event. For instance if you have a link which changes content from A to B with AJAX and after that back button would change content from B back to A, flow would be following:

1. current url is `localhost:8080/MyImdb#index` (for instance)
2. user clicks the link which has href `#example`
3. browser navigates to `localhost:8080/MyImdb#example`
4. hashchange event is fired
5. router picks the event, analyses it and changes the content from A to B
6. user hits the back button
7. browser navigates to the back to `localhost:8080/MyImdb#index`
8. hashchange event is fired
9. router picks the event, analyses it and changes the content from B to A

So don't make clicking the link to do something else than changing hash. Router handles content changes. Dojo seems to have support for this kind of thingy. I haven't tried it but demos seems to be very promising: http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/hash/. Also jQuery seems to have plugins made for this. One can be found here: https://github.com/Emberex/hashrouter

I hope this helps.